# How to set correct src path (GET localhost getting 404 (Not Found))?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have ReactJS and Webpack set up. I am correctly setting the src path yet I am still getting the following error, and I can't seem to figure out why. Tried all, such as ./, /, ../ etc. The image is called practiceImage.jpg and it is in my media folder inside public folder.

Why is it not able to find it? What should be the correct path?

In my `home-page.js` in pages folder:

```
  <div>
    <img src="../../public/media/practiceImage.jpg"
      style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
    />
  </div>
```

Yet nothing renders and I get the broken image on the browser and error `GET http://localhost:8080/public/media/practiceImage.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

And is my directory tree:

[image]

Comment: If the `public` is root folder, than use relative to root: `<img src="/media/practiceImage.jpg" />`.

Comment: @skobaljic how do you determine if something is a root folder to see if relative?

Comment: Apps usually set one folder to be public, compare other files paths as stylesheets in your folder structure to those you see on server. If your css is in `public/css/style.css` for example, but on server is `css/style.css`, than your public folder is `public` and look at it as a server root.

Comment: @skobaljic Please take a look at the image of the directory tree in the original post. my `public` folder does contain stylesheets. So the `public` folder have these two paths: `public -> stylesheets -> base.scss` and `public -> media -> practiceImage.jpg`. Based on that, what should I try out?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to wrap file paths that webpack can process in `require()` calls.

```
<img src={ require( "../../public/media/practiceImage.jpg" ) } ...
```

Further reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Comment: still no luck. It continues to say `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../public/media/practiceImage.jpg`. What could be the problem?

Comment: The file path is relative to the javascript file you're in on the filesystem. Make sure that page exists relative to the current file. You also to make sure you're using a loader that has a `test: ` regex that matches `.jpg` in your webpack config

Comment: Also you can't run that code directly in the browser / node. You have to transform the source code into a bundle that is valid browser/node javascript using webpack. Please read the article.

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, could you show an example? Made multiple attempts but no luck so far.

Comment: There are some example / boilerplate projects which are probably easiest to look at. For example this line https://github.com/react-webpack-generators/react-webpack-template/blob/master/src/components/Main.js#L6 from this project https://github.com/react-webpack-generators/react-webpack-template with a loader config like https://github.com/react-webpack-generators/react-webpack-template/blob/master/cfg/defaults.js#L48-L49

Comment: can you just show so I can accept and upvote? I've been having trouble understanding and trying since yesterday...